# Callback function for expired session for connect-redis in node.js

Tags: node.js, session, redis, session-timeout, node.js-connect

I am using Connect on node.js with connect-redis as session store. Is there a way to attach a callback function to the the event when the session expires, so I can backup data from the session, before it gets deleted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its impossible because the expiration is done at redis side. The connect-redis session store uses `setex`.

https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis/blob/master/lib/connect-redis.js#L80

You can set a insane `maxAge` and do expiration by yourself using `setInterval`

OR

Fork the module :)